# Angular2 Service not persisting data

Tags: angularjs, angular

This is my first Angular app and it's based on the [tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/).

I created a `CartService` to manage my shopping cart, a `CartComponent` to show in my navbar, and a `CartReviewComponent` for reviewing the cart.

The `CartService` is in the providers array of the `app.module.ts`. **This, I believe, essentially creates a singleton.**

The `NavbarComponent` is in the `app.component.html` file with the routing.

When a product is added to the cart, the `CartComponent` in the navbar observes the change and updates to show the total $.

As soon as I route somewhere else (another page, or cart-review) then the `CartComponent` in the navbar shows an empty cart.

How can I get the data to persist in the cart so when I change pages the cart isn't empty?

Thanks.

Here's the `CartService`:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {OrderedItem} from "../models/OrderedItem";
import {Subject} from "rxjs/Subject";


@Injectable()

export class CartService {

private orderedItems: OrderedItem[] = [];

//observable number sources
private cartPriceTotalSource = new Subject<number>();
private cartItemTotalSource = new Subject<number>();

//observable number streams
cartPriceTotal$ = this.cartPriceTotalSource.asObservable();
cartItemTotal$ = this.cartItemTotalSource.asObservable();

//message commands
addToCart(item: OrderedItem) {
    this.orderedItems.push(item);
    this.calculateCartTotals();
}

private calculateCartTotals()
{
    let items = 0;
    let price = 0;

    this.orderedItems.forEach((element) => {
        items += element.quantity;
        price += element.quantity * element.item.price;
    });

    this.cartItemTotalSource.next(items);
    this.cartPriceTotalSource.next(price);
}

}
```

*******UPDATE**********

Here's the `CartComponent`:

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {OrderedItem} from "../../models/OrderedItem";
import {CartService} from "../../services/cart.service";


@Component({
    selector: "my-cart",
    templateUrl: "app/components/cart/cart.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["app/components/cart/cart.component.css"]
})

export class CartComponent {

    itemTotal: number = 0;
    priceTotal: number = 0;

    constructor(
        private cartService: CartService
    ) {
        cartService.cartItemTotal$.subscribe(
            itemTotal => this.itemTotal = itemTotal
        );

        cartService.cartPriceTotal$.subscribe(
             priceTotal => this.priceTotal = priceTotal
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have `CartService` added to `providers: []` anywhere except in `app.module.ts`? Don't add it to any `@Component({providers: [...])`.

Comment: Yeah, nowhere but `app.module.ts`.

Comment: Can you please show us the CartComponent?

Comment: @Riv, I just added it

Comment: @MayNotBe, I'm also experiencing the same issue, have you got any further with it?

Comment: Hey, nope.  I found this thread https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4350 but it doesn't seem to apply to my situation.  Let me know if you come up with an answer please.  I'll do the same.

Comment: @TimRicker - I got it working.  I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 3):

All the code posted above seems to be correct (or correct enough for now).

My trouble was that I was navigating my routes with `href="the-defined-route"`.

The correct way is to access the `[routerLink]` directive like this:

`[routerLink]="['/the-defined-route']"`

I realize the `href` way was creating new instances of the service class and perhaps the entire navbar.

If anyone can explain exactly what was happening I would appreciate it.